# How to query specific dependency label in Solr's nested documents for NLP research?

Tags: solr, nlp

I've indexed this in Solr:

```json
[
  {
    "title": "Republican Party Platform of 1896",
    "language": "en",
    "genre": "written",
    "date": "1896-06-18",
    "author": "Republican Party Platforms",
    "body": "The quick fox jumped. I knew the girl singing in the room. The girl is singing in the room. ",
    "sentences": [
      {
        "sentence": "The quick fox jumped.",
        "parsed": [
          {
            "lemma": "the",
            "pos": "DT",
            "originalText": "The",
            "dep": "det"
          },
          {
            "lemma": "quick",
            "pos": "JJ",
            "originalText": "quick",
            "dep": "amod"
          },
          {
            "lemma": "fox",
            "pos": "NN",
            "originalText": "fox",
            "dep": "nsubj"
          },
          {
            "lemma": "jump",
            "pos": "VBD",
            "originalText": "jumped",
            "dep": "ROOT"
          },
          {
            "lemma": ".",
            "pos": ".",
            "originalText": ".",
            "dep": "punct"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "sentence": "I knew the girl singing in the room.",
        "parsed": [
          {
            "lemma": "I",
            "pos": "PRP",
            "originalText": "I",
            "dep": "nsubj"
          },
          {
            "lemma": "know",
            "pos": "VBD",
            "originalText": "knew",
            "dep": "ROOT"
          },
          {
            "lemma": "the",
            "pos": "DT",
            "originalText": "the",
            "dep": "det"
          },
          {
            "lemma": "girl",
            "pos": "NN",
            "originalText": "girl",
            "dep": "dobj"
          },
          {
            "lemma": "singe",
            "pos": "VBG",
            "originalText": "singing",
            "dep": "acl"
          },
          {
            "lemma": "in",
            "pos": "IN",
            "originalText": "in",
            "dep": "prep"
          },
          {
            "lemma": "the",
            "pos": "DT",
            "originalText": "the",
            "dep": "det"
          },
          {
            "lemma": "room",
            "pos": "NN",
            "originalText": "room",
            "dep": "pobj"
          },
          {
            "lemma": ".",
            "pos": ".",
            "originalText": ".",
            "dep": "punct"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "sentence": "The girl is singing in the room.",
        "parsed": [
          {
            "lemma": "the",
            "pos": "DT",
            "originalText": "The",
            "dep": "det"
          },
          {
            "lemma": "girl",
            "pos": "NN",
            "originalText": "girl",
            "dep": "nsubj"
          },
          {
            "lemma": "be",
            "pos": "VBZ",
            "originalText": "is",
            "dep": "aux"
          },
          {
            "lemma": "singe",
            "pos": "VBG",
            "originalText": "singing",
            "dep": "ROOT"
          },
          {
            "lemma": "in",
            "pos": "IN",
            "originalText": "in",
            "dep": "prep"
          },
          {
            "lemma": "the",
            "pos": "DT",
            "originalText": "the",
            "dep": "det"
          },
          {
            "lemma": "room",
            "pos": "NN",
            "originalText": "room",
            "dep": "pobj"
          },
          {
            "lemma": ".",
            "pos": ".",
            "originalText": ".",
            "dep": "punct"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The schema is this:

```xml
<schema name="my_schema" version="1.6">
  <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
  <field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
  <field name="language" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
  <field name="genre" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
  <field name="date" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
  <field name="author" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
  <field name="body" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
  <field name="sentences" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
  <field name="lemma" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
  <field name="pos" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
  <field name="originalText" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
  <field name="dep" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
</schema>
```

When I sent a query `http://192.168.2.10:8983/solr/#/test/query?q=*:*&q.op=OR&indent=true&useParams=`, I got this:

```json
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "indent":"true",
      "q.op":"OR",
      "useParams":"",
      "_":"1685809108520"}},
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[
      {
        "title":"Republican Party Platform of 1896",
        "language":"en",
        "region":["US"],
        "genre":"written",
        "date":"1896-06-18T00:00:00Z",
        "author":"Republican Party Platforms",
        "body":"The quick fox jumped. I knew the girl singing in the room. The girl is singing in the room. ",
        "sentences.sentence":["The quick fox jumped.",
          "I knew the girl singing in the room.",
          "The girl is singing in the room."],
        "sentences.parsed.lemma":["the",
          "quick",
          "fox",
          "jump",
          ".",
          "I",
          "know",
          "the",
          "girl",
          "singe",
          "in",
          "the",
          "room",
          ".",
          "the",
          "girl",
          "be",
          "singe",
          "in",
          "the",
          "room",
          "."],
        "sentences.parsed.pos":["DT",
          "JJ",
          "NN",
          "VBD",
          ".",
          "PRP",
          "VBD",
          "DT",
          "NN",
          "VBG",
          "IN",
          "DT",
          "NN",
          ".",
          "DT",
          "NN",
          "VBZ",
          "VBG",
          "IN",
          "DT",
          "NN",
          "."],
        "sentences.parsed.originalText":["The",
          "quick",
          "fox",
          "jumped",
          ".",
          "I",
          "knew",
          "the",
          "girl",
          "singing",
          "in",
          "the",
          "room",
          ".",
          "The",
          "girl",
          "is",
          "singing",
          "in",
          "the",
          "room",
          "."],
        "sentences.parsed.dep":["det",
          "amod",
          "nsubj",
          "ROOT",
          "punct",
          "nsubj",
          "ROOT",
          "det",
          "dobj",
          "acl",
          "prep",
          "det",
          "pobj",
          "punct",
          "det",
          "nsubj",
          "aux",
          "ROOT",
          "prep",
          "det",
          "pobj",
          "punct"],
        "id":"be5360b5-daef-4645-afe2-752a43b93628",
        "_version_":1767700593829216256}]
  }}
```

As part of NLP research work, I need to find out the dep labels the word "singe" has been assigned, which should be two, e.g. `"ROOT"` in "The girl is singing in the room.", and `"acl"` in "I knew the girl singing in the room.". How should I compose a query in Solr?

I tried this:

```
http://192.168.2.10:8983/solr/test/select?q=sentences.parsed.lemma:singe&fl=sentences.parsed.dep&rows=100
```

and only got this:

```json
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 3,
    "params": {
      "q": "sentences.parsed.lemma:singe",
      "fl": "sentences.parsed.dep",
      "rows": "100"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 1,
    "start": 0,
    "numFoundExact": true,
    "docs": [
      {
        "sentences.parsed.dep": [
          "det",
          "amod",
          "nsubj",
          "ROOT",
          "punct",
          "nsubj",
          "ROOT",
          "det",
          "dobj",
          "acl",
          "prep",
          "det",
          "pobj",
          "punct",
          "det",
          "nsubj",
          "aux",
          "ROOT",
          "prep",
          "det",
          "pobj",
          "punct"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: `sentences.parsed.lemma:singe` only limits the documents being returned, not the values in the fields being returned. However, a multi-valued field retains the sequence as it was indexed, so if you fetch both fields (`fl=sentences.parsed.lemma,sentences.parsed.dep`, you can look at what position `singe` has in that list and look up the same position in the `dep`-list. `singe` is in position 10 and 18 in the first field, and position 10 and 18 in the second field is `acl` and `ROOT`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Following this path I got the solution by using `pysolr` in Python, and the Python code returned exactly what I wanted: `['acl', 'ROOT']`